# Displaying Pandas Series with Asian text in index

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

If the index of a `Pandas` `Series` is in one of the Asian languages and has variable lengths, then the print-out would not be aligned correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.Series( range(2), index = [ 'ミートボールスパゲッティ', 'ご飯' ] )
display(df)
print(df)
df
```

[image: Output]

Note that this only happens with `Series`, with `DataFrame` `display` can display the content nicely.

How can I fix the output here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Series` to a `DataFrame` for display. [Currently](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5563), `Series` have no `to_html()` method. Therefore, they cannot be displayed in this format directly.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.Series( range(2), index = [ 'ミートボールスパゲッティ', 'ご飯' ] )
df.to_frame()
```

[image]